# Is there a CMS page before delete observer?

Tags: magento-1.9, module, extensions, event-observer, cms

First of all, I'm attempting to tap into the pre-deletion events of the following:

1. Categories
2. Products
3. CMS Pages

Categories and products are fairly straight-forward, tapping the `catalog_category_controller_category_delete` and `catalog_product_delete_before` events, respectively.  CMS pages on the other hand are another story...

I've browsed the source code inside app/code/core/adminhtml/controllers/cms/PageController.php to find the following:

```
public function deleteAction()
{
    // check if we know what should be deleted
    if ($id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('page_id')) {
        $title = "";
        try {
            // init model and delete
            $model = Mage::getModel('cms/page');
            $model->load($id);
            $title = $model->getTitle();
            $model->delete();
            // display success message
            Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addSuccess(
                Mage::helper('cms')->__('The page has been deleted.'));
            // go to grid
            Mage::dispatchEvent('adminhtml_cmspage_on_delete', array('title' => $title, 'status' => 'success'));
            $this->_redirect('*/*/');
            return;

        } catch (Exception $e) {
            Mage::dispatchEvent('adminhtml_cmspage_on_delete', array('title' => $title, 'status' => 'fail'));
            // display error message
            Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError($e->getMessage());
            // go back to edit form
            $this->_redirect('*/*/edit', array('page_id' => $id));
            return;
        }
    }
    // display error message
    Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError(Mage::helper('cms')->__('Unable to find a page to delete.'));
    // go to grid
    $this->_redirect('*/*/');
}
```

There is no indication that there is any event emitted prior to deleting a CMS page, nor does there appear to be any way to retrieve which CMS page ID has been deleted.  Am I missing something or is this just another instance of Magento's excessive inconsistency?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've implemented a (hopefully) temporary workaround by tapping into the `controller_action_predispatch_adminhtml_cms_page_delete` to accomplish the goal, however I'd like to see a more consistent solution if anyone has something clever to add.